# Finitely generated subgroups of $GL_2(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, normal-subgroups

I am trying to show that every finitely generated subgroup of $GL_2(\mathbb{C})$ contains a normal subgroup of finite index that does not contains non-trivial elements of finite order.

I know that there is a lemma on abstract algebra that shows this result for $GL_n(\mathbb{C}),$ but every proof that I saw before, has a lot of very technical/advanced steps. Is there an elementary proof for this particular case?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Nope, assuming $n=2$ does not make it any easier. Actually, you can even assume $GL(2, {\mathbb R})$, it's the same difficulty.

Comment: @MoisheKohan what a shame. Thanks. Is there a (not very advanced) textbook in which I can see a proof of this result?

Comment: @rowcol I recommend, since you are so interested in this problem, to try and prove it yourself, without refering to anything, now that you have an idea of what other proofs do.  See what you come up with and post an answer :)

Comment: "Foundations of Hyperbolic Manifolds" by John Ratcliffe.

Comment: @DanDonnelly: You are severely underestimating the difficulty of this proof.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I didn't know, sry!  I meant in general, one can / should try to prove things on their own to develop their creativity.  But if it's a 10-page proof, minimally.  Perhaps just working through the proof will suffice.  Take on half a page a day as a goal.

Comment: @DanDonnelly: Yes, in general, this is a good advice. However, take a look at my answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/369258/positive-genus-fuchsian-groups/369369) regarding the history of this result, known as Selberg's Lemma (which is actually a theorem).

Comment: The standard proof is not very difficult. Take a f.g. subgroup $G< GL_n(\mathbb C)$. Then $G$ is contained in $GL_n(K)$ where $K$ is a f.g. subfield of $\mathbb C$. Use a Noether norm. theorem that shows $K$ is a finite extension of a purely transcendental extension $L$ of $\mathbb Q$ of finite transcendental degree. So $L$ is the field of rational functions over $\mathbb Q$ with, say, $m$ variables. Since $K$ is a finite extension of $L$, $K$ embeds in a ring of matrices of finite size $s$ over $L$. Then you can embed $G<GL_k(L)$ for $k=ns$. Thus you can replace $\mathbb C$ with $L$, etc.

Comment: Note that $n=2$ in that proof does not make it simpler because eventually you have to deal with $GL_k$, $k>2$.

Comment: An easy proof by Bogdan Nika of this statement and more is here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.2385.pdf .